# Yandex cloud functions does not import module

Tags: telegram, serverless, python-3.9, aiogram

I am trying to launch my telegram bot on Yadnex cloud functions ( serverless arch ), but when i start my function I see this error (

```
{
 "errorMessage": "Unable to import module main: No module named 'bot.config'",
 "errorType": "HandlerImportError",
 "stackTrace": [" File "/function/runtime/runtime.py", line 174, in load_handler\n raise HandlerImportError('Unable to import module {}: {}'.format(file_name, str(e)))\n"]
}
```

I have a directory bot and a file called config, this file is located in bot directory
I have not got a clue, what am I doing wrong?
Please help me )

I want to launch my code on serverless cloud functions

Folders and modules:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem specific to Yandex Serverless Functions. The issue is that the Python interpreter does not account `bot` folder as a module until there is no `__init__.py` file in it. So to fix the problem, you should add the file and possibly add the same files in the directories in the `bot` as well, so they will become modules too.